# Appcelerator Titanium ReverseGeocoder certificate suddenly stopped working on iOS only

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using Appcelerator Titanium for a mobile application that has been live for more than a year.

3 days ago, the reverse geolocation stopped working without any app update.

I debugged the application and got the following error with the `Ti.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder` method :

> Le certificat d’accès à ce serveur n’est pas valide. Vous vous connectez peut-être à un serveur qui prétend être « api.appcelerator.net », ce qui pourrait compromettre vos données confidentielles.

It's french, and can be translated to something like :

> The access certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server who pretends to be « api.appcelerator.net », this might compromise your confidential data."

I can find any information regarding the deprecation of this `Ti.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder` method.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I am also getting same error from today.. It's only on iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just posted this question in Ti-Slack team & got confirmation that this issue has been resolved an hour ago.

Here's the chat!

[image]